# Different results for ezANOVA and aov in R

Tags: r, anova, repeated-measures

I'm trying to carry out a 2 (between-subjects: native, non-native) x 3 (within-subjects: £1 offer, £2.50 offer, £4 offer) mixed ANOVA, however, ezANOVA() and aov() seem to provide different results; ezANOVA() found a significant interaction term, whilst aov() didn't. Does anyone know why this could be and which results I should rely on?

Here's the code I used:

```
responder_anova <- ezANOVA(data = responder_data, 
                       dv = .(percentage_accepted), 
                       wid = .(ID), 
                       between = .(native),
                       within = .(offer_type),
                       type = 1,
                       detailed = TRUE, 
                       return_aov = TRUE)
```

and

```
resp <- aov (percentage_accepted ~  as.factor(native) * as.factor(offer_type), 
             data=responder_data)
```

Output:

```
> summary(responder_anova)

      Length Class      Mode
ANOVA 9      data.frame list
aov   3      aovlist    list

> print(responder_anova)

$ANOVA
             Effect DFn DFd        SSn      SSd          F            p p<.05        ges
1            native   1  86   3778.256 164087.7   1.980221 1.629710e-01       0.01375743
2        offer_type   2 172 144326.615 106767.9 116.253050 1.147863e-32     * 0.34762237
3 native:offer_type   2 172   5717.942 106767.9   4.605721 1.125857e-02     * 0.02067422

$aov

Call:
aov(formula = formula(aov_formula), data = data)

Grand Mean: 56.82246

Stratum 1: ID

Terms:
                   native Residuals
Sum of Squares    3778.26 164087.72
Deg. of Freedom         1        86

Residual standard error: 43.68062
2 out of 3 effects not estimable
Estimated effects are balanced

Stratum 2: ID:offer_type

Terms:
                offer_type native:offer_type Residuals

Sum of Squares   144326.62           5717.94 106767.86

Deg. of Freedom          2                 2       172

Residual standard error: 24.91472
Estimated effects may be unbalanced
```

And for `aov`:

```
    summary(
    resp <- aov (percentage_accepted ~  as.factor(native) * as.factor(offer_type), data=responder_data)
    )

                                         Df Sum Sq Mean Sq F value Pr(>F)    
as.factor(native)                         1   3778    3778   3.599 0.0589 .

as.factor(offer_type)                     2 144327   72163  68.738 <2e-16 ***

as.factor(native):as.factor(offer_type)   2   5718    2859   2.723 0.0675 .
```

Comment: Thank for your quick reply. I changed it yo type = 1, and the same problem persists. I also added the outcomes of both calculations.

Comment: OK thanks. Now I see that your `aov` call is not a repeated measures / mixed ANOVA. So it's very different from `ezANOVA`. Your `aov` call is not appropriate for your experimental design.

Comment: Do you know how I could make it appropriate?

Comment: Well, why not just use `ezANOVA`? For `aov` you'd need something like `percentage_accepted ~ native * offer_type + Error(ID/offer_type)`. But `ezANOVA` does exactly this: forms a correct `aov` call and runs it for you.

Comment: I'm using ezANOVA, however, I need to perform post-hoc tests, which is the reason why I used aov(). Do you know if there's any way to use ezANOVA for post-hoc comparisons?